# Pandas / matplotlib: stacked bar charts should overlap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting a pandas dataframe.  I have a bar chart, with `stacked=True`.  The problem is, it puts the results on top of each other, instead of overlapping.  If value `a` is 20, and value `b` is 40, the height of the bar will be 60.  What I really want is `a` from 0-20 from the axis, and `b` from 20-40 (so that values are overlapped).  Is this possible?

Comment: That's not a stacked chart, that's just a chart where the bars overlap. What would you want to happen for the next set of values if `a = 40, b = 20`, would `b` just not show up at all because it's behind `a`?

Comment: You may want to create new columns such as `b_` where `df[b_] = df.b-df.a`

Comment: If `b > a` is guaranteed for your rows, making a delta column like James suggests and calling `stacked=True` is the easiest way. Otherwise you'll need to manually do it yourself with Matplotlib.